# Relative paths in php for files

Tags: php

I want to include a class that is located directory GeoDB relative to where my calling script executes.

So I do

```
include('GeoDB/geodb.php');
```

When I instatiate:

```
$geodb = new GeoDB();
```

The constructor loads a file named geodb.json Like so

```
   function __construct(){
      $json = file_get_contents("geodb.json");
      // .... do stuff.
   }
```

The file is located in the GeoDB directory right beside geodb.php.

However when I run the script the file is not found because the file is searched within the directory of execution and not the directory relative to the location of the file that is included.

Since this function will need to be called from several places, I don't want to have to specify a constructor paramenter just to tell it where the file "geodb.json" is.

Is there anyway to tell php, when including, to search for the file in the same directory as the included path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the magic constant `__DIR__`

```
 $json = file_get_contents(__DIR__."/geodb.json");
```

[Doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Comment: Awsome!! It worked!! Thank you so much. This was driving me crazy. I was sure __DIR__ would return the workig dir, that I didn0't read the ocumentation